# Does Electron v4 support ECMAScript modules?

Tags: google-chrome, electron, es6-modules

I am writing apps using Electron. The current version, 4.0.6, is based on Node 10.11.0 and Chrome 69.0.3947.106.

I thought the latest version of Electron would support ECMAScript (ES6) modules but I have not been able to make them work, so far.  In particular, on starting the app, the line:

import { runTask } from './action';

gives the run-time error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Before I put more effort into tracking down the problems, I would like to know the status of module support in Electron.

Does Electron version 4 (Chrome 69) support ECMAScript (ES6) modules?

Comment: https://discuss.atom.io/t/does-electron-support-es6/19366/19

Comment: Do you use import syntax in your main or renderer process?

Comment: Mayank: Thanks for the link. I would like to avoid using Babel or other transpilers in Electron, because it uses only one browser technology (Chrome/V8).

Comment: @ghybs: I am trying to import in the renderer process.  Surely, a supported ES6 language feature should work everywhere, main, renderer, worker processes?

Answer (score 2):

Chrome has apparently supported them Chrome 63:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module-dynamic-import

That might mean you can use them in your front-end?

But node v11.11.0 appears to only support them with an extra flag, `--experimental-modules`:

https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

I cannot find a reference, but maybe node 10.11.0 is the same, and that will make them work on the Electron back-end too?

(Sorry, I'm still on an older Electron, and happily using old-fashioned `require()`, so cannot tell you from personal experience if it will work.)

Comment: Thanks Darren. Yes, I gave up on import and reverted to require().  It works, but I thought import would be supported by now (ES6 = 2015) and I must be doing something wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Surely you are missing the `type="module"` attribute on your `<script>` tag.

Then you will hit the file protocol issue, which you can work around by registering your own protocol, as described in [Electron ES6 module import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51113097/electron-es6-module-import)

Comment: No, because the module is not being loaded by HTML with <script>, it is being required lower down by a javascript file.
I have just one javascript file loaded by the HTML, and then it is "javascript all the way down".

Comment: Yes that is exactly the same situation. So you are mixing require and import (which you never mention in your question BTW)? Without the `type="module"` attribute set, the import syntax is invalid "all the way down".

Comment: No. I am not mixing require and import.  I require CommonJS modules and import ES6 modules.  The CommonJS approach is working, ES6 approach is not.