# Getting error "Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec" when trying to import project

Tags: javascript, html, electron, mime-types, lit-html

Trying to create some reusable components for our Electron screen using `lit-html`. When I attempt to add an example component I run into an error.

Using `electron: ^5.0.6`

Trying to import module `my-element.js` (most of this code is example code and I'm just trying to get it working)

```
<head>
    <!-- Polyfills only needed for Firefox and Edge. -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@latest/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Works only on browsers that support Javascript modules like
     Chrome, Safari, Firefox 60, Edge 17 -->
<script type="module" src="my-element.js"></script>
```

The module `my-element.js` contains the following:

```
import {LitElement, html, css} from 'lit-html';

class MyElement extends LitElement {

  static get properties() {
    return {
      mood: {type: String}
    }
  }

  static get styles() {
    return css`.mood { color: green; }`;
  }

  render() {
    return html`Web Components are <span class="mood">${this.mood}</span>!`;
  }
}

customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

When the page loads I get an error

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

I have tried different ways of importing `lit-html` but nothing has solved the error.

Ex. `import {LitElement, html, css} from '../../node_modules/lit-html/lit-html';`

Ex. `import {LitElement, html, css} from '../../node_modules/lit-html/lit-html.js';`

Answer (score 8):

#### Electron and ES modules

Recent versions of Electron support ES modules out of the box so we instinctively think that this works without problems:

```html
<script type="module" src="my-element.js"></script>
```

The thing is: if you load the main HTML file [from the local file system](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#_i5x34ucq:%7E:text=win.loadURL(%60file), all other resources are also requested with the `file://` protocol; however the HTML spec prohibits loading ES modules with such protocol for security reasons (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51113097/electron-es6-module-import/51126482)).

#### Solutions

**Serve the source files**

Use a static file server and load `index.html` from `http://localhost:<server_port>` instead of the file system (ie [`es-dev-server`](https://open-wc.org/developing/es-dev-server.html) works well with LitElement).

**Use a module bundler**

Such as Rollup or Webpack, so you only have to load the bundle as a normal script. This way you can take advantage of tree shaking to remove unused code as well as other compilation/bundling benefits.

**Use TypeScript/Babel**

Both can transform es module statements to commonjs (`require`).

**Use commonjs**

Electron's Node integration allows you to `require()` CJS modules.

**Register a custom protocol**

See [here](https://gist.github.com/smotaal/f1e6dbb5c0420bfd585874bd29f11c43).

---

**A note on bundlers**

Using a bundler may seem inconvenient because it concentrates the load on a single js file; however in Electron environments where source files are almost always inside the local package - and therefore network latency is not an issue - it may even result in an increased performance. Also, both Rollup and Webpack support code splitting and dynamic imports so you can still perfectly follow optimization patterns such as the [App Shell Model](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/architecture/app-shell).

Comment: Let me see if I understand this correctly, to use lit-html or any library that uses ES6 Modules we will have to use a bundler tool, like babel.

Comment: In electron environments, unfortunately, yes (not necessarily a bundler, others of the above solutions may be fine depending on your needs).

Comment: This is a great explanation! A good addition to what I found about addressing this issue in the browser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403478/es6-modules-in-local-files-the-server-responded-with-a-non-javascript-mime-typ

Answer (score 1):

you have to export what you want to import first, then you can do stuff. it should work fine on firefox too.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30096793)