# i need help fixing the error: Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of ""

Tags: javascript, html, css, terminal

I need help fixing the error 'Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.'. my html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>snake game (not multiplayer)</title>
    <style>
        body {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: black;
        }
        #game-board {
            background-color: #ccc;
            width:100vmin;
            height: 100vmin;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-rows: repeat(21,1fr);
            grid-template-columns: repeat(21, 1fr);
        }
        .snake {
            background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 50%);
            border: .25vmin solid black;
        }

        .food {
            background-color: hsl(50, 100%, 50%);
            border: .25vmin solid black;
        }
    </style>
    <script src='game.js' defer type='module'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='game-board'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

my game.js code is:

```
let LastRenderTime = 0;
import{ snake_speed} from './worm.js';
function main(currentTime) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
    let secondssincelastrender= (currentTime - LastRenderTime) /1000;
    if (secondssincelastrender < 1/snake_speed) return;



    console.log('render');
    LastRenderTime = currentTime;
    update();
    draw();
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(main);

function update () {

}

function draw () {

}
```

and my worm.js file code is:

```
export const snake_speed = 1;
```

I am also opening google by using the terminal command

```
"Google Chrome.lnk" --allow-file-access-from-files
```

I would try making it into a server but I think its to risky.
you might think to just go to the question ES6 modules in local files - The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type, but but i tried everything there and nothing worked. :/
What is wrong with my code that causes this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6 modules in local files - The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403478/es6-modules-in-local-files-the-server-responded-with-a-non-javascript-mime-typ). Also see [Getting error ... when trying to import project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57416942/getting-error-strict-mime-type-checking-is-enforced-for-module-scripts-per-html).

Comment: no, but it it did help me fix a different script. thanks!