# How can I import ES user modules (used in renderer process) into Electron main process

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, electron, ecma

https://github.com/Jazzepi/bunny-tracker

I'm working on a small localized database for a nonprofit Ohio House Rabbit Rescue (they're great) and I'm struggling with the deployed version of the Electron application.

When I pass messages from the renderer to the main process often times I pass entire Typescript objects. I would like to use those Typescript definitions in the main process without replicating them by hand. You can see those imports here. Anything that comes from an import starting with `./src/` is pulling from ES "user" modules.

https://github.com/Jazzepi/bunny-tracker/blob/master/main.ts

```
import { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, Menu, MenuItem, MenuItemConstructorOptions, screen, shell } from 'electron';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as url from 'url';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import Bunny from './src/app/entities/Bunny';
import * as sqlite from 'sqlite';
import { Database } from 'sqlite';
import * as log from 'electron-log';
import SQL from 'sql-template-strings';
import IPC_EVENT from './src/app/ipcEvents';
import GENDER from './src/app/entities/Gender';
import RESCUE_TYPE from './src/app/entities/RescueType';
```

The error I get when running the production-ready app image is this. I get this image in Linux using app-image and in Mac using a dmg.

```
ohrr@ohrr:~/repos/bunny-tracker$ release/bunny-tracker-2.0.0-x86_64.AppImage 
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module './src/app/ipcEvents'
Require stack:
- /tmp/.mount_bunny-45gwlx/resources/app.asar/main.js
- 
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:659:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/tmp/.mount_bunny-45gwlx/resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:43:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:577:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:715:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/.mount_bunny-45gwlx/resources/app.asar/main.js:50:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:808:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:820:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:32)
```

Everything works fine in development mode, but it can't find the modules in production deploys.

I've read about custom protocols at the below links, but they seem to be more about letting you fetch values from custom URL schemas and I want to `import` stuff not messing around with HTML.

[Electron ES6 module import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51113097/electron-es6-module-import)
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/12011
https://gist.github.com/smotaal/f1e6dbb5c0420bfd585874bd29f11c43

Any help with an answer or even just steering me in the right direction would be great! My go to solution if I can't figure this out is symlink the user imported modules into a space the main processor can actually import from.

Comment: If your project directory layout is relatively standard paths that include `src` are going to break in production. I think you need to specify `"rootDir": "src"`

Comment: @AluanHaddad electron-builder had src excluded (I think) so I'm going to remove that from exclusion and see if it  packages it up and works.

Comment: Ok but you should use rootDir if you use outDir

Comment: @AluanHaddad Those sound like webpack directives? I don't think I'm using webpack?

Comment: negative, I'm talking about tsconfig.json. I looked at your project and you have specified rootDir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`electron-builder.json` had an entry for "!src/" telling it to ignore that folder. I'm sure this made my executable bigger but I don't care about packing up a few extra text files.

Removing the `"!src/",` fixed the production runtime problem! Woot.

```
    "files": [
        "**/*",
        "!**/*.ts",
        "!*.code-workspace",
        "!LICENSE.md",
        "!package.json",
        "!package-lock.json",
        "!src/",
        "!e2e/",
        "!hooks/",
        "!angular.json",
        "!_config.yml",
        "!karma.conf.js",
        "!tsconfig.json",
        "!tslint.json"
    ],
```