# Why do we need to change Angular target to es5 to work on electronjs?

Tags: angular, electron

In order to render my Angular app inside Electronjs, I had to change the target (in tsconfig.json) from es2015 to es5. Otherwise it's a blank screen. Most tutorials say to do so, but I don't understand why.
What are the reasons?
Thank you.

Comment: It's not necessary. Could you provide more information please? Maybe github repo with an example?

Comment: Look in github, there is many sample apps, all of them have target es5, otherwise it won't work, it leads to blank screen. Example: https://github.com/rabehasy/angular-electron/blob/start/tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because since Angular 8 target defines [differential loading](https://blog.angular.io/version-8-of-angular-smaller-bundles-cli-apis-and-alignment-with-the-ecosystem-af0261112a27) process (enable es modules for modern browsers) and Electron can't load it via `file://` protocol without MIME type by HTML specification. For more information [dig here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51113097/electron-es6-module-import)

Nevertheless if you want to use es2015 target just update Electron to the latest version.